# why this code is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, boolean, ternary-operator

```
let x;
console.log("shubham" == true );  // gives false
"shubham" ? x=2 : x=3;
console.log(x); // gives 2, so "shubham" must be true?
```

//I am hoping to get value 3

Comment: It's not true, it's truthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use this:

```
"shubham" == true
```

before comparing, true turned to 1,so the actually comparsion is

```
"shubham" == 1
```

so ,it gives false;

the book:

> When performing conversions, the equal and not-equal operators follow
>   these basic rules:
>
> If an operand is a Boolean value, convert it into a
>   numeric value before checking for equality. A value of false converts
>   to 0, whereas a value of true converts to 1.
>
> If one operand is a string and the other is a number, attempt to convert the string into a number before checking for equality.

when you use this:

```
"shubham" ? x=2 : x=3;
```

works like:

```
Boolean("shubham")?x=2:x=3
```

so,it gives you x=2;

the book:

```
variable = boolean_expression ? true_value : false_value;
```

> This basically allows a conditional assignment to a variable depending
>   on the evaluation of the boolean_expression. If it’s true, then
>   true_value is assigned to the variable; if it’s false, then
>   false_value is assigned to the variable.

the book:

> Professional JavaScript for Web Developers.3rd.Edition.Jan.2012

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is due to the underlying code behind the 'if' statement in Javascript. It relies on a method 'ToBoolean' which converts the condition of the if statement to a boolean value. Any string that is not empty, is converted to true. Thus, why you get the above logic.